# Why is my dynamic physics body able to push my static physics body? In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, physics

I have a player and a wall, whenever the player walks into the wall it pushes it away. The wall is static and the player is dynamic anyone know how to fix this?

Player code:

```
player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
player.position = CGPoint(x: 0 + player.frame.width / 2,y:     self.frame.height + player.frame.height / 2)
player.zPosition = 2
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody?.pinned = false
player.physicsBody?.mass = 0.18
player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
```

Code to move the player:

```
let moveForward = SKAction.moveByX(1, y: 0, duration: 0.01)
```

Wall code:

```
backWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "up")
backWall.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
backWall.position = CGPoint(x: 0 + 35, y: ground.frame.height)
backWall.zPosition = 3
backWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
backWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
backWall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
backWall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
backWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: backWall.size)
```

Comment: That is definitely not true,  the physics will still apply, with a 0 velocity from the moving object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your wall is not dynamic,  it is still a physics body with volume and mass.  You want to use `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:)` if you want bodies that can't move and not have to worry about advanced physics being applied to it

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate an `SKSpriteNode`, its `physicsBody` is nil.

So, these lines of your code:

```
backWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
backWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
backWall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
backWall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
```

are silently ignored.

You may need to assign `SKPhysicsBody` first:

```
backWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: backWall.size)
backWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.backWall
backWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
backWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
backWall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
backWall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
```

I haven't tested your code, so you may need other parts to be fixed. Especially, I'm afraid if your `player`'s `physicsBody` is properly set up.

Comment: I did that but now the player just passes through the wall

Comment: why would the wall want to collide with the wall?  shouldn't the collisionBitMask and contactBitMask point to the player

Comment: In a context where there's no reasonable recovery behavior when something is nil you might as well just unwrap unsafely with !, so that the program can fail faster when it gets into a bad state, and you can get to troubleshooting root causes sooner.